# ECLIPSE AWS Toolkit -New RDS connection failure

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, eclipse-plugin

[image: Screenshot Attached]

In the AWS Explorer, after clicking on the Amazon RDS, selecting the database instance and attempting to connect, a new window pops up which says Configure RDS Database Connection. In the section of JDBC driver, when I’m trying to Create a New Driver Definition, the Select JAR, browse option isn’t showing any of the executable jar files in the directory.

Personal Note: Perhaps the file selection window should have included “*.jar” files instead of  only “jar” while searching for files in the directory.
I’ve checked with other jar files as well. The Select JAR isn’t showing up any of the contained jars, may it be the MySQL connector or the oracle ojdb jar.

What could be the possible solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is a bug. I renamed the driver .jar file to be simply a file named "jar".